# Problem capturing mouse left button while using WM_NCHITTEST

Tags: c, winapi

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:  { 
     LRESULT hit = DefWindowProc( hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam ); 

        if ( hit == HTCLIENT ) { 
            hit = HTCAPTION; 
            SendNotifyMessageA( hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, NULL, MAKELPARAM( LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam) ) );
            pts.x = pts.y = 0;
            ClientToScreen( hWnd, &pts );
            SendNotifyMessageA( hWnd, WM_EXITSIZEMOVE, NULL,NULL );
            return hit;
        }   } break; 
case WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN: { LMB_Dyn[h2] = true;  } break;
```

I'm using this code while I try to move a window by clicking in the client area (anywhere in window). This works fine.

But I have problem correctly receiving the state of the mouse left button and while this code kind of works the problem is that when I do a simple click instead of a "click and move" the `LMB_Dyn` variable (mouse left button) has some delay (does not immediately get notified that I pressed the mouse button.

How to correctly get the state of the mouse left button while using `WM_NCHITTEST`?

Comment: Why are you issuing `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` messages? You don't need to do that. As for your question, have a look at `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON)`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks. This part is responsible so to get the position of the window after movement and update the mouse position in client coordinates. I;ll check GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON).

Comment: GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) seems to get the state of mouse left button clicked everywhere in the screen properly but when I click on the client area of the window the update of the variable is still slow...

Comment: Stackoverflow Tip: While deleting questions that attract downvotes can protect your reptuation, it doesn't do you any good for avoiding being question banned, and only makes getting unbanned harder. Typically, once a question gets a couple of downvotes it stops getting downvotes anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Mistake: `}   } break;` should read  `}  return hit; }`

However, there's something more radical going on here. `WM_NCHITTEST` is not meant to be used like that and is allowed to be called with coordinates other than the current mouse position. This means your `SendNotifyMessageA` can send garbage.

I see you have a handler for `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`. Maybe that's all you need. Or, if you're trying to make the window draggable by anywhere on it, that should be like so:

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:  {
    LRESULT hit = DefWindowProc( hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
    if ( hit == HTCLIENT ) { 
        return HTCAPTION;
    }
    return hit;
}
```

The documentation for [`WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-nclbuttondown) and [`WM_NCLBUTTONUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-nclbuttonup) says they fire immediately. It's really easy to forget your [`InvalidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) call and so not have your screen redraw for you so it appears slow.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the WM_NCHITTEST test so to be able to move the window around by clicking anywhere at the client area and at the same time to retrieve mouse x,y in client coordinates and also to update my variables that store window position and size. (it is a multiple windows application). When I use the WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN I get the mouse left button but when I release it not when I click it... Any recommendations are welcome should I implement window movement and resizing with another function?

Comment: Also the question is how to properly retrieve mouse button state while using WM_NCHITTEST, I know how the WM_NCHITTEST test works for just moving the window around.